# Installation Solution Sharepoint Online

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I see lot of solution c# for Sharepoint but i have sharepoint online 2013 with microsoft server.

How can i install solution to my sharepoint online ?

For example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d#content

Normally I use jquery for Sharepoint but i need convert Htlm to pdf and save this to Document Library.

For Information : I use visual studio to develop xamarin applcation and plumsail forms designer to develop sharepoint forms.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please explain what  kind of Solution it is. You cant install a custom Solution with server side code in sharepoint Online. 
You might use a Sharepoint Add in. If you need Server side code you can develop a provider  hosted app instead.

Comment: Hi,

I want to convert a page of sharepoint to pdf and upload this to docuement library. I've tested jsPDF but the result is still far from satisfactory...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you need is a Sharepoint Add In. 
You are in the good road looking at some JavaScript solution.  Keep looking for a suitable one.

Comment: Maybe can you help me, i use jsPDF but i have i few problem..
Can you look this ? :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060277/aspx-to-pdf-jspdf
Thanks